# How do I print to Heroku logs from script in heroku-buildpack-python 's post_compile hook?

Tags: python, bash, heroku, github

So I wanted automated migrations for my Heroku/Github integration and I added a post compile script using [this.](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/hooks/post_compile)

The script is based on [this post](https://gist.github.com/kylefox/7044491259b6b2586ca1) and looks like this:

```
if [ $AUTO_MIGRATE == True ]; then
  echo "=> Performing database migrations..."
  python 'app_name'/manage.py migrate
else
  echo "=> Automatic migrations off! ... Not doing anything ..."
fi
```

However, I would like the output of the migration to output to the Heroku logs and not just to the build log.

How can I do this?